# Android set Activity size

Tags: android, android-layout

What I am looking for is an equivalent of SurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(), but for an Activity, where I can set the dimensions of the activity without it becoming a window on the screen.

[Android: How to set the absolute size of an Activity's Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454794/android-how-to-set-the-absolute-size-of-an-activitys-window)

I looked at a couple of answers already, but they all made the window a separate size. Using

```
getWindows().setLayout(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2)
```

or using

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();  
params.height = screenHeight/2;
params.width = screenWidth/2;
this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

will result in the activity becoming a window, like so (dark gray part is the activity). Essentially, I want the dark gray part (the activity) to fill the entire screen, but have the dimensions that I assign to it, just like SurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(), but with an Activity.
[image]
[image: What I'm aiming for]

Comment: can you provide any example screen shot or any such thing of what you want exactly

Comment: I want the activity to fill the entire screen, so the entire screen should be that shade of gray (second picture).

Comment: I'm sorry I did not get you ... but this is the normal behaviour of the activity,it anyway fills the entire screen...

Comment: Have you tried adding this code to your theme 
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
..................
       <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
....................
    </style>

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I get the same result.